# How to rotate bones and keep animation?

Tags: animation, bones, baking

This problem is a little bit wonky on the computer's side but I want to see if I can make this work.
Basically, I need to rotate every bone on this character 90 degrees on the x-axis for it to be properly interpreted.
[image]

The problem is that when I rotate every bone 90 degrees on the x-axis I get a jumbled mess of bones.

[image]

Is there a way for me to bake the keyframes so that I can rotate the bones but still have the same animation? Thanks for help my guys.

Comment: Could you please clarify How you have the armature this way up, and  the desired result. (perhaps on a two or three bone test rig) Bones have a hierarchy, rotating a parent affects the children. Doing so for all bones most likely creates the mess that you have above. Most importers / exporters have the option to change the UP and FORWARD axis. Am of the opinion this is what you want to do here.  Could be a matter of rotate rig object 90 degs in x and apply... hard to tell without further clarification.  [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an empty object or a not used armature and use object constraint field , then use a copy transform constraint and choose empty or dummy bone to control your bones location.
in addition to that you can use riggify addon built in blender to add a preset rig for your models just activate it in preferences .

[image]